# What is the easiest way to move images, clipboard, links from iOS to a Windows PC and vice versa?

Tags: windows, ios, iphone-app

I've used PushBullet in the past but it's been so neglected and now barely works. I've also tried ShareIT, and couldn't make it work either.

What can I use to accomplish this task today?

Answer (score 2):

This might sound ridiculous, but I've been using Slack for this.

Personally I've chosen to create my own workspace for it, but messaging yourself in any existing workspaces you're in will also work.

A feature / downside (depending on your view) is that you don't get a notification.